# How to properly connect PHP files using include

Tags: php

I am attempting to create a some type of framework that i can use for all my future PHP project, that all that i need to do is copy the folder on my website root and call the `require_once` function and all the plugins/helpers will be loaded.

On my index.php i declare it like this.

`require_once('framework/install.php');`

inside my install.php i have below.

```
//GLOBALS VARIABLES HERE
define("hostname", "localhost");
define("URL", "http://" .hostname. "/mywebsite/");

include('autoload.php'); // this part is my problem.

//CLASSESS HERE
```

Now inside my `autoload.php` i have a code that auto include all files inside a folder called plugins.

```
        $autoload = array('database','extensions');

        foreach (glob(URL ."plugins/*.php") as $autoload) // URL was defined on my install.php
        {
            include $autoload;
        }
```

On `database.php` and `extensions.php` i have a `echo "This is loaded"`. but i cannot get the `This is loaded` to display any suggestions to execute this properly?

### Edit

To share my solution, this is what i did i choose to put the name of the plugin inside a `array` so that i can get to choose what to load from the plugin directory maybe i can put a functionality in the future to install plugins like wordpress, if there any way to improve this i would appreciate it.

```
 $autoload = array('database','extensions');

            $dir = __DIR__."/plugins/";    
            $files = scandir($dir);  

            foreach($autoload as $file) {


                    include ($dir.$file.".php");

            }
```

---

Comment: You're trying to `glob` a URL, that won't work. `glob('http://yahoo.com/*')`? Nope. You'll want to work on *local directory paths!*

Comment: You cannot include PHP files from the URL it should be the local paths.

Comment: When you say work with local files then i should use the `__FILE__` or `__DIR__` on my for each code? sorry about that.

Comment: Ok i got it working using `scandir` instead.

Comment: Yes that would be great also.